# WCF service to handle HTTP GET requests

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

Ive got a requirement to create a WCF service which sits on a server (hosted in IIS) and listens to any HTTP GET requests that hit the server at a certain URL.

More specifically when a valid GET request hits the server, Id like to inspect the parameters encoded in the URL.

The following is the code for my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHttpHandler
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
    void HandleMessage(Message m);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "HandleEchoRequest", Method = "GET")]
    string HandleEchoRequest(Stream request);
}
```

Implementation code (svc.cs file):

```
public void HandleMessage(Message m)
{
    //do some work
}

public string HandleEchoRequest(Stream request)
{
    //...do something here
    return "asdf";
}
```

I can successfully hit the SVC:

```
http://localhost/HttpMessageProcessor/HttpHandler.svc
```

However, I cant seem to step in to the break-point set when attached to the W3WP process. Ultimately Id like to use HTTPS.

My web.config file in the WCF service project:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

App.config in the client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHttpHandler" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/HttpMessageProcessor/HttpHandler.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="Proxy.IHttpHandler" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHttpHandler" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client code:

```
using (var service = new Proxy.HttpHandlerClient())
{
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I tried two things to see if I can step into the code:
1. Hit <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> on the console project to start the client and then see if I can attach to W3WP process.
2. Run the client in debug mode and see if I can point to a URL such as:

```
http://localhost/HttpMessageProcessor/HttpHandler.svc/HandleEchoRequest/
```

None of the above methods seem to work.

Ive already had a look around the net for suggestions and tried a few things and Ive rested on the code Ive mentioned here. Any suggestions/ideas welcome!

**EDIT**
I came across [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/817bfbd7-82ef-4210-aa44-ac076540a540/) website and implemented a simple solution as follows.
I can successfully hit the breakpoint set in the implementation of HandleMessage when I enter the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost/TestWCFSite/TestWCFService.svc/HandleMessage
```

Code:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
     [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
     void HandleMessage(Message m);
 }

 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
     public void HandleMessage(Message m)
     {
        //do something here.
     }
 }
```

App.config for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My client code:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/TestWCFSite/TestWCFService.svc/");
Uri endpointAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/TestWCFSite/TestWCFService.svc/HandleMessage/");
var binding = new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.None, Encoding.UTF8), new HttpTransportBindingElement());
ServiceHost service = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, endpointAddress);
service.Open();

var message = string.Format("Service open at {0} - press a key to continue", baseAddress);

Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadKey();
service.Close();
```

My problem is now trying to host this in IIS and get it to process the breakpoint hit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio - what happens if you attach through Tools->Attach to Process...?

Just to double-check, I assume you're attaching from the WCF service project rather than the client project?
(My apologies for making this an answer, me rep is too low to make comments.)

Comment: Hey, yup - using Visual Studio. Ive got the client and WCF service in the same solution. When I attach, it says that the client code will not be stepped into.. makes sense. The WCF code is bright red which means it should hit...